# Is improper integrability equal to integrability in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, + \infty)$ is a positive measurable function that is improper integrable. Can we then conclude that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable?

I think this should be true, but I don't know how to argue that it is.

$\textbf{EDIT: }$ Since $f$ is improper integrable and Riemann integrals are equal to Lebesgue integrals on closed bounded intervals we have that in the limit of the improper integral the f is Riemann integrable, thus also Lebesgue integrable, where we use some kind of indicator function. Then by the monotone convergence theorem we can bring the limit inside. Hence integrability is proven. I still have some issues with writing this down though, how can I differentiate the notation of the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals?

Comment: You should review [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/148510) and revise accordingly before this gets closed.

Comment: @RRL what's wrong with my question?

Comment: @RRL my bad, I was in a time crunch writing it down, I'll try to update whenever I have the chance!

Comment: Think about the monotone convergence theorem and the equivalence of the Lebesgue and Riemann integrals on bounded intervals.

Comment: @RRL I know that Lebesgue and Riemann integrals are equal on closed bounded integrals! How could I apply the monotone convergence theorem though?

Comment: @RRL I have posted an edit, but I still have some issues writing the proof down, also shouldn't the integral in your comment go from $- \infty$ to $+ \infty$ instead of $0$ to $+ \infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is given that $f:\mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ is improperly integrable. I take that to mean that the improper (Riemann) integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx $ exists, and, by definition,  $f$ is Riemann integrable on any finite interval $[a,b]$ and the limits

$$\lim_{a \to -\infty}\int_a^c f(x) \, dx, \quad\lim_{b\to +\infty}\int_c^b f(x) \, dx,$$

exist and are finite for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$, so that we can define (uniquely)

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\, dx = \lim_{a \to -\infty}\int_a^c f(x) \, dx + \lim_{b\to +\infty}\int_c^b f(x) \, dx$$

It also follows that we can evaluate the improper integral (where $n$ is a positive integer) as

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\, dx=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^n f(x) \, dx$$

Since $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[-n,n]$, the Lebesgue integral exists over that interval and

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f \chi_{[-n,n]} = \int_{[-n,n]}f = \int_{-n}^n f(x) \, dx$$

Since $f\chi_{[-n,n]} \to f$ as $n \to \infty$, and $f$ is nonnegative, we can apply the monotone convergence theorem and obtain

$$0 \leqslant\int_{\mathbb{R}}f = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}f \chi_{[-n,n]} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx< + \infty$$

Comment: Great!! Your notation makes everything much much clearer. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Geigercounter: You're welcome.